# read lists from .txt file python

Tags: python, list

I want to create .txt which contains several lists

```py
a = ['210','210','210','210']
b = ['0.3','0.3','0.3','0.3']
c = ['7.85e-06','7.85e-06','7.85e-06','7.85e-06']

with open("abcd.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(str(a))
    
with open("abcd.txt", "a") as output:
    output.write(str(b))
    
with open("abcd.txt", "a") as output:
    output.write(str(c))
```

So test file is generated like

```
['210', '210', '210', '210']['0.3', '0.3', '0.3', '0.3']['7.85e-06', '7.85e-06', '7.85e-06', '7.85e-06']
```

Now I want to extract the first element of all lists.
How can I do that?
Here each list contain 4 elements but it may be higher that also.

Comment: read all numbers before the first `]`

Comment: try this: `print(open("abcd.txt").readline().split("]")[0].replace('[', ""))`

Comment: Do you need to support nested lists? Like `['1', ['2a', '2b'], 3]`

Comment: @Adirio ..no nested list is not there ..

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan It is giving the output like '210', '210', '210', '210' . But I want like first element of list a then first element of list b and then first element of list c

Comment: why no `'\n'` between the lists? then you had 1 list per line and could concentrate on parsing a list per line? Which btw is handled here: [eval-vs-ast-literal-eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution using `regex`,

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/GrNDfA/1)

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval

with open('abcd.txt', "r") as f:
    for x in re.findall(r".+?\]", f.read()):
        print(literal_eval(x)[0])
```

---

```
210
0.3
7.85e-06
```

Comment: `eval`, or in this case `ast.literal_eval` is the reason why I think storing as plain text is not a very good idea. Now anyone can edit the file, place some python code ending in `#]` to trigger your pattern and that code will be run. I know that `eval` is the easiest way to parse a list which would require a lof of string parsing but that's the main reason why formats like CSV and JSON already have their parsers in the standard library so that you can store them in a file and retrieve them later without the need to `eval` potentially malicious code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.index()` to find the position of ']' and `.count()` to find how many of them you have:

```py
with open('abcd.txt', 'r') as input:
    content = input.read()


strings = []
start = 0
for _ in range(content.count(']')):
    end = content.index(']', start) + 1
    strings.append(content[start:end]
    start = end

for string in strings:
    print(string[1:string.index(',')])
```

The second argument to `.index()` tells it from which position to start searching from, in order to avoid returning always the position of the first ']'.

Output:

```
'210'
'0.3'
'7.85e-06'
```

However, if you are going to store data in a file, I suggest you do it in something a bit more structured like JSON which every language has a parser for.

Answer (score 1):

firstly read the file and store the data in a variable.

```
with open('abcd.txt','r') as myFile:
    data = myFile.read()
```

then remove the first and last square brackets because they are not needed.

```
data = data[1:-1]
```

then split the data from '][' because this is where two lists meet.

```
lists=data.split("][")
```

then get the first values of all elements and store it in another list like:

```
firstelements = []
for aList in lists:
    firstelements.append(aList.split(",")[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can work with json (why not??) - here is a json based solution

```
import json

a = ['210', '210', '210', '210']
b = ['0.3', '0.3', '0.3', '0.3']
c = ['7.85e-06', '7.85e-06', '7.85e-06', '7.85e-06']

data = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c}

# save to a json file
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)

# read from json file and get the data you need
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
first_values = [x[0] for x in data.values()]
print(first_values)
```

output

```
['210', '0.3', '7.85e-06']
```

Comment: May I suggest moving the last two statements out of the `with` block as there is no reason to keep that file opened?

Comment: @Adirio makes sense.

Comment: @balderman this is working good in windows but in linux it is giving error like...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled3 (Run from Script Editor)", line 10, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: 'data.json'

Comment: Disk is full. Check it.

Answer (score -1):

You can concatenate strings using the `+` operator.  Try this:

```
a = ['210','210','210','210']
b = ['0.3','0.3','0.3','0.3']
c = ['7.85e-06','7.85e-06','7.85e-06','7.85e-06']

to_save = str(a) + str(b) + str(c)
with open("abcd.txt", "wb") as output:
    output.write(to_save)
```

If you want to duplicate the code it might be better to write it as a function.

Comment: This is not an answer, you suggested an improvement on part of the code he provided but the question was about reading not about writing. Not trying to sound too harsh.